# How to get value from HashMap when we have User object as key like below

Tags: java, hashmap

In below I want the value 400 which need to print by passing its key. May I know how to do it.?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Student, Integer> hmap=new HashMap<Student, Integer>();

    hmap.put(new Student(101, "Srinu", 5000), 100);
    hmap.put(new Student(102, "Srinu", 5000), 200);
    hmap.put(new Student(103, "Srinu", 5000), 300);
    hmap.put(new Student(104, "Srinu", 5000), 400);

    System.out.println(hmap.get(new Student(104, "Srinu", 5000)));
    System.out.println(hmap.containsKey(new Student(104, "Srinu", 5000)));

  }
```

Comment: Your code should work, as long as you override `hashCode` and `equals` properly in the `Student` class.

Comment: Give the detail of `Student` class. You need to override `boolean equals()` and `hashCode()` of `Student` class

Comment: When I over ridden equlas() and hashCode() it returned the value 400 and true. Why it has't gave the result before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method of your `Student` class. Let your IDE auto generate those two.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two methods in your Student.java file:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + no;
    result = prime * result + num;
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (no != other.no)
        return false;
    if (num != other.num)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I believe after adding these two methods, your code will work fine.